# Underclock Nvidia Multiple Monitor

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop with Nvidia Geforce Go and nvidia drivers.  My laptop screen is broken so I connect to an external monitor and disable the first.  The nvidia gpu is constantly at highest  and heats up my laptop.  I still want the driver for 3d but I want to be able to control it.  Is there any hack I can do to underclock or switch to nouveau drivers and switch back to Nvidia when neccesary?

Answer (score 0):

In a manner of speaking, yes.

```
sudo nvidia-settings
```

Then, in the left column, look for an entry called PowerMizer, and set mode Adaptive instead of Maximum Performance.

Otherwise/Also, find a way to cool your laptop (ie using a laptop cooler).